# TikZ: underline node-text as a style

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to *underline node-text as a style*?

I tried something like

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
execute at begin node={\underline{ },
execute at end node={ } },
]{Some text that should be underlined.};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

but this gives not a good result: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this ?

Edit: with hpekristiansen'comment

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  % soul/.style args={#1}{label={\underline{#1}},node contents=},%<-- bof   
  soul/.style args={#1}{node contents={\underline{#1}}},%<-- with  hpekristiansen'comment  
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[soul=Some text that should be underlined.];
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the use of the `label` and deleting contents. It makes other labels difficult and the spacing wrong. Simply do this: `soul/.style args={#1}{node contents=\underline{#1}}`.

Comment: @hpekristiansen indeed, what you propose is much better, I modified the answer

Answer (score 4):

You could use the same trick as in @Skillmon's great answer https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=6276#a6152

(compile with TL2023, there seems to be a problem with TL2024)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\myunderline{}{
  \@underLine
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[font=\myunderline]{Some text that should be underlined.};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]