# Underlining across multiple paragraphs

Tags: xetex, underline

I’m producing syntax-highlighted LaTeX via fancyvrb. It all works well – unless styles cross lines. I have a workaround but the output would be more concise if there were a LaTeX command for underlining across multiple paragraphs:

- Package `soul` didn’t work and was generally brittle for me (especially when I mixed styles, added colors, etc.).
- The closest I got was the code shown below. Alas, paragraph 1 & 2 are displayed in a single line. The italics in P3 and P4 works as desired.
- I’m using Tectonic (=XeLaTeX).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\uldecor}{\textul}

\begin{document}
  {\uldecor
    Paragraph 1

    paragraph 2
  }
  
  {\itshape
    Paragraph 3

    Paragraph 4
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you can switch to lualatex, you could use the same approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711470/36296 https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFrnN.png

Comment: Thanks! I’m not yet ready to give up Tectonic but that’s good to know.