How to make underline work like bfseries?
I want to define a command \bflikeuline which works like \bfseries. Namely, \bflikeuline some text will underline some text. I tried the following code:
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\bflikeuline}{}
\begin{document}
    \bflikeuline this is a test
\end{document}

However, it doesn't work, and an error File ended while scanning use of \UL@on. throwed while compling. However, the following works.
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\bflikeuline}{}
\begin{document}
    {\bflikeuline this is a test}
\end{document}

How to make \bflikeuline work without the surrounding curly brackets?

I don't think that is possible. Being bold is a font feature, so can be switched on and off. Underlining is a construction. It litteraly needs to know where it has to end.

You could use lua-ul and do something like this: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=6276

Here an example with underline: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711470/36296

Underlines in documents are like unwelcome guests at a formal party. Always end up drawing too much attention and ruining the elegance of the event. :)
